# What's going on with this method overloading?

Tags: c#, overloading

I have a question about method overloading in C#.  I have a parent class and a child class.

```
class Parent
{
    public virtual string GetMyClassName()
    {
        return "I'm a Parent";
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public override string GetMyClassName()
    {
        return "I'm a Child";
    }
}
```

I have two static methods declared outside of those two classes that act on objects of either type:

```
static string MyClassName(Parent parent)
{
    return "That's a Parent";
}

static string MyClassName(Child child)
{
    return "That's a Child";
}
```

When I test out how these methods are all called, I get what I think is a strange result:

```
Parent p = new Child();
var str1 = MyClassName(p); // = "That's a Parent"
var str2 = p.GetMyClassName(); // = "I'm a Child"
```

Why does `str1` get set to "That's a Parent"?  I am probably misunderstanding method overloading in C#.  Is there a way to force the code use the Child call (setting str1 to "That's a Child")?

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095544/overloaded-method-why-is-base-class-given-precedence

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does str1 get set to "That's a Parent"?

Because overloading is (usually) determined at *compile-time*, not execution time. It's based purely on the compile-time types of the target and arguments, with the exception of calls using `dynamic` values.

In your case, the argument type is `Parent`, so it calls `MyClassName(Parent)`

> Is there a way to force the code use the Child call (setting str1 to "That's a Child")?

Two options:

- Declare `p` as being of type `Child`, not `Parent`
- Declare `p` as being of type `dynamic`, which will force the overload resolution to be performed at execution time

Comment: Option 3: Call a single method and then check the type.

Comment: Wow, I've never come across a use for `dynamic` outside of Excel com interop calls before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Method **overload** resolution happens at *compile time*, while virtual method **override** resolution happens at *run time*.

Your call to `MyClassName()` is being resolved at compile time to the `Parent` overload because the type of `p` is `Parent`.  Since the `Child` object is actually an instance of `Parent` too (due to inheritance) this is not a problem.  (Note that `p instanceof Parent` is true, even if `p` references a `Child` object.)